# ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE unresolved reference

Tags: java, android, kotlin

This code works well in Java but in Kotlin not:

```
import android.widget.ListView

myListView = getListView(....)
myListView!!.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE)
```

The constant `CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE` isn't found. When I click on `ListView` it takes me to `public class ListView extends AbsListView {` which is the right place where `ListView` is located.

Why is that?

Comment: try cleaning and rebuilding

Answer (score 3):

Static variables and methods cannot be called on subclasses in Kotlin. `AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE` is the correct way to call them.

Comment: are you sure they can't, do you have the link?

Comment: http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#accessing-static-members It doesn't say it explicitely, but it's how the compiler works anyway.